# Couchbase java N1QL DSL query statement with IN expression

Tags: java, couchbase, dsl, sql++

Trying to write a N1QL query like

```
SELECT * from bucket
WHERE s IN ["s1", "s2", ..., "sn"]
END;
```

in DSL. Assuming I have a list of Strings called s_array, I need to write something like this:

```
select("*").from("bucket")
.where(x("s").in(s_array);
```

Whats the best way to write the IN expression in DSL without concatenating all list elements in a String or something?

Comment: did u try s_array as JSONArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the JsonArray overload, as so:

```
select("*").from("bucket")
            .where(x("s").in(JsonArray.from("s1", "s2", "s3"));
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing 
```
select("*").from("bucket")
            .where(x("s").in(JsonArray.from(s_array));
```
Thanks